# How to process a class in remote machine?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

Usually we can use java reflection to get a class by simply doing `Class.forName("fully qualified class name")`.

Now I have a class file `(.class)` located in client machine.  For example, if the client machine is windows and the the class file `myClass.class` is located in `c:\tmp\myClass.class`.  I have to "process" this class file in another machine in the server to know the class's methods etc.

Please do not ask why this is needed:-)  Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: is that you mean you want to load a remote class file into your jvm or you want to execute the class in remote location..? Please be specific..

Comment: My purpose is to know the class's method, which can be done through the Class object. So I think I only need to load the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make use of Network class loader here. Check [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/classloaders-140370.html) out.

URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new 
URL("http://123.321.456.121:8080/test/") });

Class c = loader.loadClass ("Hello");

Object o = c.newInstance();

Comment: Can I use URL for a local file like "c:\tmp\myClass.class"?    Can it be accessed from another machine?

Comment: How to get the URL for file "c:\tmp\myClass.class" in machine A, and load it in machine B? I might have done it wrong, as it does not work.

Comment: Just do new File("c:/tmp/myClass.class").toURI().toURL(); or for Java7+ Paths.get("c:/tmp/myClass.class").toUri().toURL()